# Suggestion for PID Tuning

Tags: microcontroller, pid-controller

Hello friends I'm currently working on a project on my university stabilizing a thermal unit with a cooling fan I used a pretty basic PID design being suggested by Application Note from Atmel itself.
Also looked at GitHub quite other PID controllers so I doubt there is a coding issue.

The system output from the PID looks like this.
[image]

The system is oscillating but shouldn’t the temperature at one point try to settle?

Comment: So where did your PID values came from and which algorithm you used to tune them?

Comment: @justme what I  did is put randmom PID values that is what I'm essentially asking what would be the best way to find the right ones if I can't have a model of the system.

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound harsh but information on how to manually tune PID controllers is very easy to find. If we take the time to read this, maybe it would be good if you took the time to read that? And if you still have problems afterwards then by all means ask a question here :)

Comment: Have a look at Eurotherm's [PID control made easy](https://www.eurotherm.com/temperature-control/pid-control-made-easy/).

Comment: And for a little more detail:  [PID without a PhD](https://www.wescottdesign.com/articles/pid/pidWithoutAPhd.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

> Question: "shouldn’t the temperature at one point try to settle?"

Answer: Just looking at the plot, the system is not going to settle (converge), since the amplitude of the oscillation is amplifying over cycles. It can stably oscillate to a certain frequency (f = 1 / (1400-1300)), unless it starts widen (lower frequency) at saturation.

From a brief observation, you need to consider a few factors to tune the system (P,I,D):

1. Fans are slow responding devices. Effectiveness depends on ambient temperature (inlet temp).
2. In the plot, cooling and heating are asymmetric, heating response (un-cooling) takes longer time than cooling.

a) Just briefly from my past memory, manual tuning; The first thing people usually do is considering enough filtering (simple first order LPF), then decide the overall response time. This as well defines sampling/cycle time.

b) I=0, D=0, find P to just enough large, as you prefer, may be just before oscillation. If this cannot settle the oscillation, go back to finding good amount of filtering

c) Once you get the system working with P, adjust I, adjust D, re-adjust P, while observing the effect of these parameters.

Comment: i did your method and im currently seing improvements already my PID works and I would like to say thanks a lot for your help even my supervisor could not help me as much as you did thanks a lot for your answer really.